# Find column by column name and keep specific value of that column and remove all other data including blanks

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA macros. I am trying to create a macro that that finds column name "Load Type" applies filter  on column value LCL and keep only data rows with LCL and removes rest all data rows.
Example Macro should work like

1. Search column named "Load Type"
2. Select/ Filter column Value with LCL
3. Remove all other data other than LCL
   If column named "Load Type", value <> LCL then entire row delete.

I want the macro to keep only data with value LCL in column named Load Type and remove rest all data even if there is blank it should remove the entire row if load type is blank.

[image: Original Excel]

Column N heading is Load type has multiple values LCL, Blanks, BB. I want the macro to keep only data and corrospoding row with column "Load Type" value LCL and remove rest all data.

[image: Desired out]

Desired output is in above image.

My coding image
[image: My code]

I tried coading like this but its says variable not defined I am confused of do i fix this.

```vb
Sub SortLCL_Concat()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sRng As Range
Dim fRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim tRow As Long
Dim fCol As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set fRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

fCol = fRng.Column

tRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

For tRow = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
If .Cells(tRow, fCol).Value <> LCL Then .Rows(tRow).Delete
Next tRow
End With

End Sub
```

I want the macro to keep only data with value LCL in column named Load Type and remove rest all data even if there is blank it should remove the entire row if load type is blank.

Comment: You have to type LCL with quotation marks:  `.value <> "LCL"` only then it gets recognized as string. Plus: put `Option explicit` at the top of the module to be sure to declare all variables.

Comment: Noted I made the changes and when I run the macro it give type mismatch error at below line in the code 
Set fRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")` returns the **worksheet** of the **active workbook**. But you want a range: e.g. `Set fRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").UsedRange`. But be careful: you first set `wb` as `ThisWorkbook`, then you use ActiveWorkbook - `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` might be different (read the documentation). I suppose what you want is to use `wb` throughout the code instead of ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: even afterching that it is giving same error at line "
Set fRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")" type mismatch

Comment: Does the **active** workbook have a sheet "Main"? Did you add `.UsedRange`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete Data Rows Using `AutoFilter`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SortLCL_Concat()

    Const wsName As String = "Main"
    Const FilterColumnTitle As String = "Load Type"
    Const FilterCriteria As String = "<>LCL"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim fCol As Long: fCol = Application.Match(FilterColumnTitle, rg.Rows(1), 0)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    rg.AutoFilter fCol, FilterCriteria
    
    Dim vdrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vdrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If vdrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    vdrg.Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```